# Google Drive API bad request from C# but fine from Postman

Tags: c#, http, google-api

I'm using this request code from C# and getting a Bad Request result:

```
    public class GoogleDriveManager
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        private const string Access = "ACCESS";

        public GoogleDriveManager()
        {
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Access);
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFilesAsync(string driveId)
        {
            var url =
                $"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?driveId={driveId}&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&corpora=true&supportsAllDrives=true";
            var result = await Client.GetAsync(url);
            return result;
        }
   }
```

But when I make the same sort of request from Postman, it works great:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?driveId=DRIVEID&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&corpora=drive&supportsAllDrives=true

(Authorization Bearer Token, with token value the same as the one used above)

What am I doing wrong on the C# side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) supported values for corpora are:

- user
- domain
- drive
- allDrives

Your Postman example has corpora=drive but your C# example shows corpora=true.

Comment: *head hits desk*